# Digital filter and std::inner_product optimization

Tags: c++, filtering, numeric

In a digital filtering C++ application, I use `std::inner_product` (with `std::vector<double>` and `std::deque<double>`) to compute the dot product between the filter coefficients and the input data, for each data sample. After profiling my application, I figured out that no less than 85% of the execution time is spent in `std::inner_product`!

To what extend is `std::inner_product` optimized, in GCC for example?
Does it uses SIMD instructions? Does it performs loop unrolling? How to make sure of that?
Based on this, would it worth it to implement custom dot product function(s) (especially if the number of coefficient is low)? (but I would like to keep the function as generic as possible)

More specifically, this is the piece of code I use to apply a filter:

```
std::deque<double> in(filterNum.size(), 0.0);
std::deque<double> out(filterDenom.size() - 1, 0.0);
const double gain = filterDenom.back();

for (unsigned int s = 0, size = data.size(); s < size; ++s) {
    in.pop_front();
    in.push_back(data[s] / gain);

    data[s] = inner_product(in.begin(), in.end(), filterNum.begin(),
        -inner_product(out.begin(), out.end(), filterDenom.begin(), 0.0));

    out.pop_front();
    out.push_back(data[s]);
}
```

Typically, I use second order bandpass IIR filters, which means that the size of `filterNum` and `filterDenom` (numerator and denominator coefficients of the filter) is 5. `data` is the vector containing the input samples.

Comment: Did you profile a debug build? What you expect to take more time in your application? Is it fast enough anyway?

Comment: I did profile the application with callgrind, with GCC options -O1 -g. As the application apply thousands of filters, the result I get is not surprising. I already use OpenMP to apply several filters in parallel (and it works very well, I have got a x24 in speed on my Xeon 2 x 6 cores machine). However, the task is still huge and if I could get even a x2 in speed, over 1h of execution time it is far from being negligible! And it is not a run-only-once type of application...

Comment: Just write it with double arrays longhand; it'll take 10 minutes and you can compare performance.  I suspect you will be shocked at how "fast" deque and inner_product really are (make sure you don't rotate arrays though, try to simulate what deque is doing internally).

Comment: OK, now we all want to see how much faster the pure version gets.  Add a comment with the results when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Getting an additional factor of 2 out of this shouldn't be hard if you just write the code directly.  Part of it might come from removing some of the generality of inner_product, but some would also come from such things as eliminating the use of deques - if you just keep a pointer into your input array you can index off it and off the filter array in the inner loop, and increment the pointer to the input array in the outer loop.

Each of those inner_products has to use iterators through deques,

Most of the (coding) effort then becomes handling the edge conditions.

And take that division out of there - it should be a multiplication by a constant calculated outside the loop.

Inner product itself is pretty efficient (there's not much to do there), but it needs to increment two iterators on each pass through the inner loop.  There is no explicit loop unrolling, but a good compiler can unroll a loop that simple.  And a compiler is more likely to know how far to unroll a loop before running into instruction cache issues.

Deque iterators are not nearly as efficient as ++ on a pure pointer. There is at least a test on every ++, and there may be more than one assignment.

This is what a simple (FIR) filter can look like, without including the code for the edge conditions (which goes outside of the loop)

```
double norm = 1.0/sum;
double *p = data.values(); // start of input data
double *q = output.values();  // start of output buffer
int width = data.size() - filter.size();
for( int i = 0; i < width; ++i )
    {
    double *f = filter.values();
    double accumulator = ( f[0] * p[0] );
    for( int j = 1; j < filter.size(); ++j )
        {
        accumulator += ( f[i] * p[i] );
        }
    *q++ = accumulator * norm;
    }
```

Note that there are messy details left out, and this is not the same as your filter, but it gives the idea.  What's inside the outer loop easily fits in a modern instruction cache.  The inner loop may be unrolled by the compiler.  Most modern architectures can do the add and multiply in parallel.

Comment: +1.  I bet it improves by more than a factor of 2.  Most the work being done in the example is getting data in and out of deques and traversing them.  Just do the processing in place, right on the `data` array and have `out` be a pre-allocated vector you can just write output to the right position.  Signal processing is one place you want to ditch all of the fancy data structures and just use buffers of raw memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask GCC to computes most of the algorithms in `<algorithms>` and `<numeric>` in parallel mode, it may give a performance boost if your data set is very high (I think that it really only uses OpenMP inside).

However on small datasets it may give a performance hit.

A comparison with the other solution would be more than welcome!

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html